# Should I have less tables and use complex queries to fetch data or have more tables to simplify queries?

Tags: database-design, database-table

Let's take a senario where user is tracking `traffic` for certain `cities`. The traffic is updated every two hours and we've to keep previous data to plot graph. So I've a `traffic_stats` table which looks like this -

```
traffic_stats(id,city_id,user_id,traffic,created_at)
```

(given traffic is a number)

There is a stats refresher daemon which takes the **unique** `city_id`s, gets current traffic stats for these cities and adds new entry to this table itself. The daemon uses this query to fetch `city_id` -

```
SELECT * FROM traffic_stats GROUP BY city_id
```

and adds new entry for each `city_id` in the same table. The `user_id` attribute for each new entry is 0 since it doesn't matter which user has subscribed for the city. If the `city_id` is in the table, it's traffic_stats is refreshed.

On the front end, following query is run to fetch data for user -

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM traffic_stats WHERE user_id = #{session[:user_id]} ORDER BY created_at DESC)
as traffic_for_user_in_descending_order 
GROUP BY city_id
```

This gives **single *latest*** entry for a city_id.

This should work fine except for the fact that if 100 users are tracking 200 unique cities, there will be 200 new entry in the `traffic stats` table every two hours. That's
2400 entries a day and the table will keep growing.

Now, I could have had one table which has data about the cities that users are tracking and another table that the refresher daemon adds entry to. But I'm not sure if there's any performance advantage to this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to create a separate *City* table, that way you can query the distinct city ids from that rather than scanning the whole table in the first select statement. It would also make reading the database a bit easier. If you'd rather not do this, I would suggest using `SELECT DISTINCT city_id FROM traffic_stats`. This way you will be retrieving less information.

Having a single table seems reasonable in this case, as the application you are using the information for is simple. As for historical data, it might be nice to create a separate table to store aggregated information. You could prune the primary table, selecting and storing averages for a particular length of time (day, week, month, etc.), and then filter even more by basing information off of the user id. This would cut down on the database disk usage and query time.

Personally I like to break things out as much as possible. It does make for more complicated queries, but it makes using and reading information from a database much easier in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. I realised breaking things is actually the best way to go ahead with it, even though it adds couple more tables.

Why would you suggest DISTINCT over GROUP BY ?

Comment: `distinct` ignores all of the unnecessary information, which means you only retrieve the column you need and it will be faster to retrieve it than having the database sort all of the results it finds

Comment: Alright. I need couple more columns for the View to render. In that case, I don't think it's possible to use DISTINCT and say, get the "id" column simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You should break out the `city_id` and `user_id` in a separate table like `user_city`. Then a query like `SELECT DISTINCT city_id from user_city` will give you the list of tracked cities for the daemon. The growing size of the table should not matter if you have the indexes, FKs, etc. correctly setup.

If the `user_id` is always 0 in `traffic_stats` then how does `WHERE user_id = #{session[:user_id]}` in your query work?

A complex query which uses all the possible indexes is fine. If you are doing stat summaries on a daily/weekly basis, then you should also create a table to store the aggregate data as rallsi23 suggested. So that you're not reading every row of the stats table to generate the output/report to the user.

Comment: I wasn't testing with enough data/user accounts. The query isn't running and I'm about to redo the database.